# Struggling with a map-reduce in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

**Problem**

I have a document with a `_id` and a Collection of `Answers` I am trying to write a map-reduce function to sum the total score of answers for each id.

**Document**

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("527b6ba88d251d58a18f3f0a"),
  "Answers" : [{
      "Score" : 2
    }, {
      "Score" : 0
    }, {
      "Score" : 2
    }, {
      "Score" : 2
    }]
}
```

Here is the Map-Reduce I though would be correct reading the documentation

**Map**

```
function() {
    this.Answers.forEach(function(val)
    { 
        emit(this._id, val.Score); 
    });
}
```

also tried this

```
function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.Answers; i++)
    { 
        emit(this._id, this.Answers[i].Score); 
    }
}
```

**Reduce**

```
function(key, values) 
{
    return Array.sum(values);
}
```

I am getting no information back with this, but it does appear to be processing it takes 2-5 seconds to return. I guess I am not understanding something about map-reduce.

Also I am using MongoVUE to access MongoDB.

**EDIT**

I just ran my map reduce through the console and got this output

```
{
        "results" : [ ],
        "timeMillis" : 2506,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 1655,
                "emit" : 0,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1,
}
```

so it's my map function that's incorrect I guess as nothing was emitted.

**EDIT 2**

Updated document with output from mongovue

Comment: I am trying to learn map-reduce so am using this as my test data.  I know the aggregation framework might normally be better suited.

Comment: Its not emitting at all and I agree it should be, all I can think is that your schema is not what you think it is, though the second piece of code has a syntax error, it should be: `for (var i = 0; i < this.Answers.length; i++)`

Comment: I have updated the document this is cut and paste from mongoview text view of the collection.

Comment: Can you try the second version of the for loop but with the change I state?

Comment: that was the problem :S obviously been looking at this too long.  put as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript loops adding the `length` property allows you to iterate by the count of the items in the array, so you cna change your second attempt to:

```
function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.Answers.length; i++)
    { 
        emit(this._id, this.Answers[i].Score); 
    }
}
```

It should also be noted that your reduce can run multiple times per key, specifically it can repeat every 101 rows, technically this shouldn't matter since you are summing up the array values and the previous reduce value will be passed as an array element in the new reduce so it should work just fine; however, good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'this' variable is not what you expect in the .forEach() function in your map method. Try this instead;

```
function() {
    var row = this;
    this.Answers.forEach(function(val)
    { 
      emit(row._id, val.Score); 
    });
}
```